# gradle kotlin DSL scala & idea

Tags: scala, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How can I set

```
idea {
    targetVersion = "13"
}
```

and

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

from the scala plugin https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html when building using the gradle kotlin dsl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the target version of IDEA is a simple copy-paste:

`build.gradle:`

> ```
> idea {
>     targetVersion = "13"
> }
> ```

`build.gradle.kts:`

```
idea {
    targetVersion = "13"
}
```

Setting the `sourceCompatibility` is a bit trickier:

`build.gradle:`

> sourceCompatibility = 1.8

`build.gradle.kts:`

```
 tasks.withType<ScalaCompile> {
     sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
 }
```

Do note however, that the [Gradle Scala plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html#sec:scala_cross_compilation) state that the `sourceCompatibility` option is basically a no-op. The compatible Java version is determined by the Scala compiler, where 2.11.x targets Java 1.6, and 2.12.x targets Java 1.8